# Store data in BEAN (Spring Boot REST)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am creating a REST API with Spring Boot. Most of the data come from a database but some data is fetched from third-party APIs. The problem is some of them have access limitations like max 10 requests per minute or something.
Now I am looking for a method to cache the data in my spring application and only update it every few seconds. Storing it in the db and updating it every 10 seconds is a little bit too much since the fetched data is about 1000 rows. So I thought I simply store it in my service bean.

This is my approach so far. (Coded in Kotlin)

```
@Service
class MyService(){

    var myData: CustomDataObject

    fun getData() = myData

    fun updateData(){
       // call API and store in myData Object
    }

}
```

It works but it seems kinda hacky to me. Not really a clean solution, is it? 
If someone has a better approach to this I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for me the answer is pretty obvious: use [Spring Cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).